# Can the focal length be changed while animating?

Tags: animation, workflow

I would like for the focal length of the camera to shift from 20 to 200 as the animation progresses.  Is this possible ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. The Focal Length field can be keyframed with the <kbd>I</kbd> command just like any other field. Hover the mouse over the field and press the I key to insert a keyframe at the current frame of the timeline.

[image]